# Stack overflow at LayoutLinks specs from railstutorial.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to follow THE magnificient Rails3 tutorial at http://railstutorial.org but ran into a problem in chapter 5.

How ironic, but i'm getting stack overflow running these LayoutLinks ([http://railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec:integration_tests](http://railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec%3aintegration_tests)) specs.

This is the output:

```
C:\sample_app>rspec spec\requests\layout_links_spec.rb
FFFFFF

Failures:
  1) LayoutLinks should have a Home page at '/'
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Home")
     stack level too deep
     # ./spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb:7

  2) LayoutLinks should have a Contact page at '/contact'
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Contact")
     stack level too deep
     # ./spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb:12

  3) LayoutLinks should have an About page at '/about'
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector('title', :content => "About")
     stack level too deep
     # ./spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb:17

  4) LayoutLinks should have a Help page at '/help'
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Help")
     stack level too deep
     # ./spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb:22

  5) LayoutLinks should have a Help page at '/help'
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Help")
     stack level too deep
     # ./spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb:27

  6) LayoutLinks should have a signup page at '/signup'
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Sign up")
     stack level too deep
     # ./spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb:32

Finished in 206.38 seconds
6 examples, 6 failures
```

The code and specs ought to be the same as on that tutorial (i copy-pasted).

Any ideas what might be happening here?

I tried to run specs with -b to get more stacktrace but it didn't work for some reason.

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 3.0.1 and RSpec 2.1.0 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are running into this Webrat issue: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues#issue/140.

Try downgrading to Webrat 0.7.1 in your gemfile.

Comment: Woho, that was it! Thanks for the tip!